# How can i print in a new column the total count for 1 column in KSH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, ksh

Im trying to add a new column in txt file with the total count without delete other columns, already found a post here in stackoverflow but

```
cut -f1 test.txt | uniq -c | join -2 2 test.txt -
```

is not working for me, neither the other option in post, i mean in that post didnt answer my question, can someone help?

test.txt:

```
Apple_1   1      300
Apple_2   1      500
Apple_2   500    1500
Apple_2   1500   2450
Apple_3   1      1250
Apple_3   1250   2000
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Apple_1   1      300    1
Apple_2   1      500    3
Apple_2   500    1500   3
Apple_2   1500   2450   3
Apple_3   1      1250   2
Apple_3   1250   2000   2
```

Already tried with some regex and awk such:

```
awk '{count[$1]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}' file

awk '{ print $0 "\t" ++count[$1] }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the file twice, once to calculate the counts, and a second time to print all the lines with the count appended.

```
awk 'FNR == NR {count[$1]++; next}
     {print $0 "\t" count[$1]}' file file
```

`FNR == NR` is true when reading the first file.